# Clone laptop SSD to bigger SSD via USB HDD - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ssd, clone, clonezilla, disk-cloning

What would be the easiest way to do the above, having in mind that the usb HDD is not empty (but it has more than enough room for the SSD contents) and that it doesn't have a OS, and also, that I don't have the sata/usb cable to connect the new SSD externally?

Proprietary software will work, Clonezilla Live could also work but it seems more complicated...

Thanks!

[EDIT] Depending on the users needs, Macrium Reflect or Samsung Data Migration can help with this.

Comment: Clonezilla would work for sure... Also, https://www.urbackup.org/ has a small server install and then a client install which you can install on both the same machine while it's running. Once bot are installed and you set the backup location, just right click on the little white tray bar icon it create and select create full image backup and it'll do that with Windows booted. You then boot to the URBackup boot ISO and it'll find server and the image and you can tell it to push it to the other disk with options from there. Just some quick ideas only that's I've used in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but from what I understand, you have 3 drives.

Drive 1 is the small SSD;

Drive 2 is the HDD;

Drive 3 is the large SSD;

Your data is on Drive 1, and to transfer it to Drive 3, you move the data to Drive 2, then put Drive 3 in the computer and copy data from Drive 2.

I have two options for how to do this.

1) Get another USB drive (8GB or so), and make a bootable Linux drive.  When you boot your computer into Linux, the OS only sees a bunch of files with funny extensions.  You can't just copy/paste some files while in Windows because it sees some of the files as important system files that you cannot edit.  For help on making a bootable Linux drive, [see this website.](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)  I have done this exact same method and it works great.

You would then boot your computer into Linux with your drives attached.  You can try copying them over by selecting and dragging, but it might not work if your files are user-specific (Desktop, etc).  In that case, you could open up Terminal and type "sudo nautilus", which opens another file viewer that you should be able to access your files on.

2) Use a program like [Macrium Reflect](https://www.macrium.com/).  For Macrium specifically, it's a really easy process and there is a free 30-day trial.

Comment: I did it with Macrium. The only extra thing I needed was a USB stick where Macrium needed to install WinPE to boot it. Easy and fast. Thank you!